# PHP MySQL fetch result and display

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, fetch

Trying to learn some more PHP and MySQL here now, and I'm having problems understanding how this works. I do know other languages, so I'm hoping I will understand PHP much better if I just can get some help with this example:

I have a table called files. This contains 3 rows (3 files), where I've defined fileID, thumbURL, fullRUL, and stuff like that.

on my webpage I want to fetch this whole list of items/files, and do a for loop to display them all.

This is my PHP code, which of course repeats itself 3 times but it displays the same information, because it only uses the same row:

```
    <div id="contentWrapper">
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++){
        echo "<div id='contentItem'>";
        echo "<a href='".$row['fullURL']."' title='".$row['description']."'><img src='". $row['thumbURL']."' width='200px' height='150px' /></a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is the code where I get the data from the database:

```
    <?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
mysql_select_db("login",$db) or die("Kan ikke koble til databasen");

$filesSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files");
$numItems = mysql_num_rows($filesSQL);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE fileID=1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if (false === $result) {
echo mysql_error();
}

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
?>
```

The current example here does only fetch the firsst row and stores that in an array, so thats why I get the same values on all 3 items.

But I've tried using $filesSQL[$i]['thumbURL'] and other similar methodes, but I cant get it to work.

I guess this is a very basic question, so I'm hoping for an answer that will help me understand how to work with databases, arrays and displaying it.

---

I can easily do this in Actionscript3 or other languages, but not in php! =S

Thanks! =D

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions : [Read more...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks. What should I use instead of the mysql_ functions?

Comment: What Matt suggested :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your `for` loop, try using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "<div id='contentItem'>";
       echo "<a href='".$row['fullURL']."' title='".$row['description']."'><img src='". $row['thumbURL']."' width='200px' height='150px' /></a>";
       echo "</div>";
}
```

In this case, `mysql_fetch_assoc` is doing basically the same thing as `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)` without the numeric keys. It's up to you which you use there really.

For future database interactions, though, I'd recommend reading into either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as the `mysql` prefix and functions using it are now deprecated.

Edit:

As requested by a few users, an example using the updated MySQLi functions instead:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: ".$db->connect_error);
}
$filesSQL = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files");
$numItems = $db->num_rows; //this can also be done procedurally as mysqli_num_rows($filesSQL)
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileID = 1");
if(!$sql) {
    echo $db->error;
}
//personally, if I wanted an SQL error after a query I would use:
$sql = $db->query('query') or die($db->error);

//then to follow, your while loop becomes
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { //can also be done with object as $row = $sql->fetch_assoc
    //do your loop
}
```

Sadly, I'm not aware of PHP templates as suggested by Your Common Sense in the comments, so examples for that are welcome!

Comment: Thanks, will try this. However, as DarkBee said, I would like to learn this the proper way, and if mysql_ functions are outdated, what should I use instead? =)

Comment: I put links to the 2 successors to `mysql_` in my answer, MySQLi and PDO. I personally use MySQLi for most things these days, the syntax is very similar. Your connection just becomes `$sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);`, queries are as easy as `$result = $sql->query($query);` :)

Comment: This answer is bad for two reasons: it encourage outdated library usage (an example outweigh a 1000 links) and ugly HTML/PHP mess instead of using templates and logic separation. Practically throws the OP back in PHP stone age.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I've updated the answer with a MySQLi example as well, however an example on PHP templating as you suggested is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it have to be

```
<?php
// connect (better to be moved into included file)
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$db = new PDO($dsn,"xxxxx", "xxxxx", $opt);

// getting files
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files");
$files = $stmt->fetchAll();

//output
?>
<div id="contentWrapper">
<?php foreach($files as $row): ?>
    <div id='contentItem'>
        <a href="<?=$row['fullURL']?>" title="<?=$row['description']?>">
            <img src="<?=$row['thumbURL']?>" width='200px' height='150px' />
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Learn more on [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)